# CSS looking funky in Safari & Mobile

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, safari

Below are two images from my website (overrealmgame.com/Database), the first from Chrome (how it should look), the second from a mobile device. As you can see, instead of the white being centered in the middle, it's anchored to the left. Any idea what CSS changes would fix this? Thanks.

[Chrome Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl2lO.png)

[Mobile Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRpbO.png)

CSS:

```
body {
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
color: #545454;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1100px;
min-height: 800px;
padding: 2em 2em 4em;
background: rgba(1, 165, 45, 0.25);}
```

Comment: Can you share HTML and CSS code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is because of the margin:auto. Basically in the desktop one, there is free space on either side so the margin causes it to center. on the mobile one, there isn't any free space so it doesn't have any room to center. It looks like the size of your items are going past the size of the parent container too. All of these things together are creating the problem. I can't see the styling for the rest of the page, but it looks like your components are not the sizes you think they are. What I would suggest doing is opening your dev tools and inspecting the elements. It should tell you how much space each item is takig up on the screen as well as the margin/padding of the items. This should help you get started with seeing why this is happening. Also it will help if you debug using the mobile version from the desktop instead of actually opening it from your phone. Chrome has an option to be able to view as a different device.